# how to print well formatted java code in JSP or consol form database?

Tags: java, jsp

database using MYSQL.
IDE using eclipse .
server using Tomcat.
 problem scenario is facing difficulty in print the formatted java code on jsp or console

```
 java code example[
1. class One {
2. public static void main(String[] args) {
3. int assert = 0;
4. }
5. }
1. class Two {
2. public static void main(String[] args) {
3. assert(false);
4. }
5. }
```

] is stored in the database when retrieved that java code is printing in a single line on the console or jsp .
how to print it in a proper formatted  java code
 please give an appropriate solution...

Comment: take a look at [Jalopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jalopy/) for programmatically formatting Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<pre>` HTML tag:

```
<pre><c:out value="${theJavaCode}"/></pre>
```